# Issue in storing Mysql Data From Flask to jinja (HTML) variable as json

Tags: python, mysql, json, flask, jinja2

Scenario : I am trying to fetch a table data in flask. The data is retrieved properly and I am trying to convert that data to json and send it to the page where its being rendered.

Flask code

```
data =core.distinctState() #This method gets the required data 
return render_template("index.html", data=json.dumps(data))   # converting data to json format
```

Java script Code

```
var distinctState = [{{data|tojson|safe}}];
```

but my data is like a complete json string. How do i fix this ?

Sample data :

```
var distinctState = ["[[1, \"Delhi\"], [2, \"Gujarat\"], [3, \"Karnataka\"], [4, \"Gujarat\"], [5, \"Gujarat\"], [6, \"Gujarat\"], [7, \"Gujarat\"], [8, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [9, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [10, \"Assam\"], [11, \"Telangana\"], [12, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [13, \"West Bengal\"], [14, \"Bihar\"], [15, \"Rajasthan\"], [16, \"Odisha\"], [17, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [18, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [19, \"Maharashtra\"], [20, \"Maharashtra\"], [21, \"West Bengal\"], [22, \"Bihar\"], [23, \"Bihar\"], [24, \"West Bengal\"], [25, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [26, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [27, \"Haryana\"], [28, \"Uttarakhand\"], [29, \"Maharashtra\"], [30, \"Karnataka\"], [31, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [32, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [33, \"Uttarakhand\"], [34, \"Uttarakhand\"], [35, \"Uttarakhand\"], [36, \"Uttarakhand\"], [37, \"Uttarakhand\"], [38, \"Gujarat\"], [39, \"Gujarat\"], [40, \"Gujarat\"], [41, \"Gujarat\"], [42, \"Gujarat\"], [43, \"Gujarat\"], [44, \"Gujarat\"], [45, \"Gujarat\"], [46, \"Gujarat\"], [47, \"Gujarat\"], [48, \"Gujarat\"], [49, \"Gujarat\"], [50, \"Gujarat\"], [51, \"Gujarat\"], [52, \"Gujarat\"], [53, \"Gujarat\"], [54, \"Gujarat\"], [55, \"Gujarat\"], [56, \"Gujarat\"], [57, \"Gujarat\"], [58, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [59, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [60, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [61, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [62, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [63, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [64, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [65, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [66, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [67, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [68, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [69, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [70, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [71, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [72, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [73, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [74, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [75, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [76, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [77, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [78, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [79, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [80, \"Kerala\"], [81, \"Kerala\"], [82, \"Kerala\"], [83, \"Kerala\"], [84, \"Puducherry\"], [85, \"Puducherry\"], [86, \"Maharashtra\"], [87, \"Delhi\"], [88, \"Punjab\"], [89, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [90, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [91, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [92, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [93, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [94, \"Sikkim\"], [95, \"Meghalaya\"], [96, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [97, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [98, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [99, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [100, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [101, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [102, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [103, \"Mizoram\"], [104, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [105, \"Punjab\"], [106, \"Rajasthan\"], [107, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [108, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [109, \"Gujarat\"], [110, \"Bihar\"], [111, \"Bihar\"], [112, \"Bihar\"], [113, \"Bihar\"], [114, \"Sikkim\"], [115, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [116, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [117, \"West Bengal\"], [118, \"Andaman and Nicobar Islands\"], [119, \"Karnataka\"], [120, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [121, \"Telangana\"], [122, \"Tripura\"], [123, \"Assam\"], [124, \"Assam\"], [125, \"Assam\"], [126, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [127, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [128, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [129, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [130, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [131, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [132, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [133, \"Gujarat\"], [134, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [135, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [136, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [137, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [138, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [139, \"Delhi\"], [140, \"Assam\"], [141, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [142, \"Uttarakhand\"], [143, \"Maharashtra\"], [144, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [145, \"Assam\"], [146, \"Assam\"], [147, \"Assam\"], [148, \"Assam\"], [149, \"Assam\"], [150, \"Assam\"], [151, \"Assam\"], [152, \"Bihar\"], [153, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [154, \"West Bengal\"], [155, \"West Bengal\"], [156, \"West Bengal\"], [157, \"West Bengal\"], [158, \"West Bengal\"], [159, \"Karnataka\"], [160, \"West Bengal\"], [161, \"Uttarakhand\"], [162, \"Uttarakhand\"], [163, \"Uttarakhand\"], [164, \"Maharashtra\"], [165, \"Bihar\"], [166, \"Uttarakhand\"], [167, \"Bihar\"], [168, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [169, \"Bihar\"], [170, \"Bihar\"], [171, \"Telangana\"], [172, \"Telangana\"], [173, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [174, \"Telangana\"], [175, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [176, \"Telangana\"], [177, \"Karnataka\"], [178, \"Telangana\"], [179, \"Telangana\"], [180, \"West Bengal\"], [181, \"West Bengal\"], [182, \"Bihar\"], [183, \"Jharkhand\"], [184, \"Odisha\"], [185, \"Jharkhand\"], [186, \"Jharkhand\"], [187, \"Bihar\"], [188, \"Bihar\"], [189, \"Assam\"], [190, \"Assam\"], [191, \"Tripura\"], [192, \"Odisha\"], [193, \"Odisha\"], [194, \"Odisha\"], [195, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [196, \"Odisha\"], [197, \"Odisha\"], [198, \"Jharkhand\"], [199, \"Odisha\"], [200, \"Gujarat\"], [201, \"Odisha\"], [202, \"Odisha\"], [203, \"Odisha\"], [204, \"Odisha\"], [205, \"Odisha\"], [206, \"Odisha\"], [207, \"Chhattisgarh\"], [208, \"Chhattisgarh\"], [209, \"Chhattisgarh\"], [210, \"Chhattisgarh\"], [211, \"Jharkhand\"], [212, \"Chhattisgarh\"], [213, \"Maharashtra\"], [214, \"Maharashtra\"], [215, \"Kerala\"], [216, \"Kerala\"], [217, \"Kerala\"], [218, \"Kerala\"], [219, \"Bihar\"], [220, \"Bihar\"], [221, \"Bihar\"], [222, \"Bihar\"], [223, \"Maharashtra\"], [224, \"Bihar\"], [225, \"Bihar\"], [226, \"Bihar\"], [227, \"Bihar\"], [228, \"Bihar\"], [229, \"Bihar\"], [230, \"Bihar\"], [231, \"Bihar\"], [232, \"Maharashtra\"], [233, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [234, \"Bihar\"], [235, \"Kerala\"], [236, \"Goa\"], [237, \"Assam\"], [238, \"Assam\"], [239, \"Assam\"], [240, \"Assam\"], [241, \"Assam\"], [242, \"Assam\"], [243, \"Assam\"], [244, \"Assam\"], [245, \"Assam\"], [246, \"Karnataka\"], [247, \"Bihar\"], [248, \"Bihar\"], [249, \"Bihar\"], [250, \"Haryana\"], [251, \"Bihar\"], [252, \"Bihar\"], [253, \"Bihar\"], [254, \"Bihar\"], [255, \"Bihar\"], [256, \"Bihar\"], [257, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [258, \"Manipur\"], [259, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [260, \"Delhi\"], [261, \"West Bengal\"], [262, \"West Bengal\"], [263, \"West Bengal\"], [264, \"Maharashtra\"], [265, \"Maharashtra\"], [266, \"Kerala\"], [267, \"Kerala\"], [268, \"Kerala\"], [269, \"Kerala\"], [270, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [271, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [272, \"Gujarat\"], [273, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [274, \"Gujarat\"], [275, \"Gujarat\"], [276, \"Odisha\"], [277, \"Odisha\"], [278, \"Odisha\"], [279, \"Odisha\"], [280, \"Odisha\"], [281, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [282, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [283, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [284, \"Maharashtra\"], [285, \"Kerala\"], [286, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [287, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [288, \"Nagaland\"], [289, \"Nagaland\"], [290, \"Gujarat\"], [291, \"Gujarat\"], [292, \"Gujarat\"], [293, \"Maharashtra\"], [294, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [295, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [296, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [297, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [298, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [299, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [300, \"Rajasthan\"], [301, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [302, \"Chhattisgarh\"], [303, \"Assam\"], [304, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [305, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [306, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [307, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [308, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [309, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [310, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [311, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [312, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [313, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [314, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [315, \"Uttarakhand\"], [316, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [317, \"Delhi\"], [318, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [319, \"Goa\"], [320, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [321, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [322, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [323, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [324, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [325, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [326, \"Telangana\"], [327, \"Telangana\"], [328, \"Goa\"], [329, \"Chhattisgarh\"], [330, \"Chhattisgarh\"], [331, \"Chhattisgarh\"], [332, \"Odisha\"], [333, \"Odisha\"], [334, \"Maharashtra\"], [335, \"Maharashtra\"], [336, \"Maharashtra\"], [337, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [338, \"West Bengal\"], [339, \"West Bengal\"], [340, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [341, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [342, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [343, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [344, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [345, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [346, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [347, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [348, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [349, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [350, \"Karnataka\"], [351, \"Karnataka\"], [352, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [353, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [354, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [355, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [356, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [357, \"Rajasthan\"], [358, \"Rajasthan\"], [359, \"Rajasthan\"], [360, \"Rajasthan\"], [361, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [362, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [363, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [364, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [365, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [366, \"Assam\"], [367, \"Jharkhand\"], [368, \"Maharashtra\"], [369, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [370, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [371, \"Karnataka\"], [372, \"Karnataka\"], [373, \"Karnataka\"], [374, \"Karnataka\"], [375, \"Karnataka\"], [376, \"Karnataka\"], [377, \"Maharashtra\"], [378, \"Tripura\"], [379, \"Odisha\"], [380, \"Odisha\"], [381, \"Odisha\"], [382, \"Odisha\"], [383, \"West Bengal\"], [384, \"Karnataka\"], [385, \"Jharkhand\"], [386, \"Bihar\"], [387, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [388, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [389, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [390, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [391, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [392, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [393, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [394, \"Karnataka\"], [395, \"Karnataka\"], [396, \"Karnataka\"], [397, \"Karnataka\"], [398, \"Karnataka\"], [399, \"Karnataka\"], [400, \"Karnataka\"], [401, \"Karnataka\"], [402, \"Karnataka\"], [403, \"Karnataka\"], [404, \"Telangana\"], [405, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [406, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [407, \"Haryana\"], [408, \"Punjab\"], [409, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [410, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [411, \"Uttarakhand\"], [412, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [413, \"Odisha\"], [414, \"Maharashtra\"], [415, \"Odisha\"], [416, \"Karnataka\"], [417, \"Odisha\"], [418, \"Odisha\"], [419, \"Odisha\"], [420, \"Assam\"], [421, \"Bihar\"], [422, \"Bihar\"], [423, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [424, \"Bihar\"], [425, \"Punjab\"], [426, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [427, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [428, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [429, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [430, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [431, \"Karnataka\"], [432, \"Gujarat\"], [433, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [434, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [435, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [436, \"Assam\"], [437, \"Assam\"], [438, \"Assam\"], [439, \"Assam\"], [440, \"Rajasthan\"], [441, \"Karnataka\"], [442, \"Rajasthan\"], [443, \"Rajasthan\"], [444, \"Rajasthan\"], [445, \"Rajasthan\"], [446, \"Rajasthan\"], [447, \"Rajasthan\"], [448, \"Rajasthan\"], [449, \"Uttarakhand\"], [450, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [451, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [452, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [453, \"Assam\"], [454, \"Assam\"], [455, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [456, \"Jharkhand\"], [457, \"Assam\"], [458, \"Assam\"], [459, \"Assam\"], [460, \"Jharkhand\"], [461, \"Bihar\"], [462, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [463, \"West Bengal\"], [464, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [465, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [466, \"Uttarakhand\"], [467, \"Bihar\"], [468, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [469, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [470, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [471, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [472, \"Assam\"], [473, \"Meghalaya\"], [474, \"Meghalaya\"], [475, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [476, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [477, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [478, \"West Bengal\"], [479, \"West Bengal\"], [480, \"Kerala\"], [481, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [482, \"Karnataka\"], [483, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [484, \"Odisha\"], [485, \"Maharashtra\"], [486, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [487, \"Odisha\"], [488, \"Odisha\"], [489, \"Kerala\"], [490, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [491, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [492, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [493, \"Gujarat\"], [494, \"West Bengal\"], [495, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [496, \"West Bengal\"], [497, \"West Bengal\"], [498, \"West Bengal\"], [499, \"West Bengal\"], [500, \"Maharashtra\"], [501, \"Kerala\"], [502, \"Maharashtra\"], [503, \"West Bengal\"], [504, \"West Bengal\"], [505, \"West Bengal\"], [506, \"West Bengal\"], [507, \"West Bengal\"], [508, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [509, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [510, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [511, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [512, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [513, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [514, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [515, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [516, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [517, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [518, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [519, \"Puducherry\"], [520, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [521, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [522, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [523, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [524, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [525, \"Telangana\"], [526, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [527, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [528, \"Telangana\"], [529, \"Odisha\"], [530, \"Haryana\"], [531, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [532, \"Bihar\"], [533, \"Jharkhand\"], [534, \"Rajasthan\"], [535, \"Uttarakhand\"], [536, \"Karnataka\"], [537, \"Bihar\"], [538, \"Maharashtra\"], [539, \"Karnataka\"], [540, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [541, \"Maharashtra\"], [542, \"Assam\"], [543, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [544, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [545, \"Odisha\"], [546, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [547, \"Punjab\"], [548, \"Karnataka\"], [549, \"Karnataka\"], [550, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [551, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [552, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [553, \"Rajasthan\"], [554, \"Punjab\"], [555, \"Jharkhand\"], [556, \"Punjab\"], [557, \"Uttarakhand\"], [558, \"Uttarakhand\"], [559, \"Maharashtra\"], [560, \"Kerala\"], [561, \"Haryana\"], [562, \"Karnataka\"], [563, \"West Bengal\"], [564, \"Maharashtra\"], [565, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [566, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [567, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [568, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [569, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [570, \"Jharkhand\"], [571, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [572, \"Rajasthan\"], [573, \"Andaman and Nicobar Islands\"], [574, \"Kerala\"], [575, \"Bihar\"], [576, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [577, \"Bihar\"], [578, \"Bihar\"], [579, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [580, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [581, \"Jharkhand\"], [582, \"Bihar\"], [583, \"Bihar\"], [584, \"Kerala\"], [585, \"Punjab\"], [586, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [587, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [588, \"Maharashtra\"], [589, \"Union Territory of Damman \u0026 Diu\"], [590, \"Telangana\"], [591, \"Maharashtra\"], [592, \"West Bengal\"], [593, \"Telangana\"], [594, \"Jharkhand\"], [595, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [596, \"Bihar\"], [597, \"Uttarakhand\"], [598, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [599, \"Maharashtra\"], [600, \"Punjab\"], [601, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [602, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [603, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [604, \"Gujarat\"], [605, \"Jharkhand\"], [606, \"Maharashtra\"], [607, \"Andhra Pradesh\"], [608, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [609, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [610, \"Karnataka\"], [611, \"Karnataka\"], [612, \"Bihar\"], [613, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [614, \"Punjab\"], [615, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [616, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [617, \"Uttarakhand\"], [618, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [619, \"Jammu and Kashmir\"], [620, \"Delhi\"], [621, \"Jharkhand\"], [622, \"Meghalaya\"], [623, \"Tamil Nadu\"], [624, \"Gujarat\"], [625, \"Karnataka\"], [626, \"Rajasthan\"], [627, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [628, \"Chhattisgarh\"], [629, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [630, \"Telangana\"], [631, \"Karnataka\"], [632, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [633, \"Karnataka\"], [634, \"Uttarakhand\"], [635, \"Arunachal Pradesh\"], [636, \"Haryana\"], [637, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [638, \"Uttarakhand\"], [639, \"Madhya Pradesh\"], [640, \"Andaman and Nicobar Islands\"], [641, \"Andaman and Nicobar Islands\"], [642, \"Maharashtra\"], [643, \"Himachal Pradesh\"], [644, \"Uttar Pradesh\"], [645, \"Goa\"], [646, \"Madhya Pradesh\"]]"];
```

Comment: You seem to be converting to JSON twice; once in the handler, and once in the template. Don't do that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It was a stupid thing. It worked like charm after removing json.dumps()